# How can I use box.com to sync my home directory across machines?

Tags: sync, webdav

Box.com does not support Linux, although there is a [feature request](https://support.box.com/entries/21546216-linux-sync) with enthusiastic support.

The comments to the feature request provide a number of ways to use Box with Linux, by mounting a WebDav folder.

Here are some example solutions using WebDav or otherwise:

1. http://maketecheasier.com/auto-mount-box-net-to-linux-desktop/2012/03/27
2. http://dev.modmancer.com/index.php/2011/12/17/access-box-com-box-net-from-your-ubuntu/
3. boxlinux: https://github.com/sebastiansam55/boxlinux
4. Conduit https://live.gnome.org/Conduit

Would any of these solutions be reasonably stable and bug-free?

Of course there are other great services (UbuntuOne, Dropbox, etc), but my institution has signed up for Box (and I thus have the space that I will require).

Comment: For me the solution on this site:  http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/08/map-box-com-storage-ubuntu-desktop/   worked like a charm!

Answer (score 11):

Officially Box Sync client for Linux does not have and has no plans for development because it is not a priority. Although this method can assess alternative.

First of all you need to install the davfs2 package. You can do this by issuing the following command in terminal: (or you can also use your favorite package manager to install WebDAV)

```
sudo apt-get install davfs2 
sudo adduser username davfs2
```

Now you should create a dedicated box.com folder.

```
mkdir /home/username/box.com
echo "https://dav.box.com/dav /home/username/box.com davfs rw,user,noauto 0 0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
sudo chmod u+s /usr/sbin/mount.davfs
```

Now you have to switch to a regular system user. This can be accomplished by issuing the following command:

```
su username
```

Next you should disable the file locks in your davfs2 configuration file, insert your box e-mail and password, change the privileges to the secrets file containing your credentials and finally to mount your account:

```
echo "use_locks 0" > ~/.davfs2/davfs2.conf
```

If this command gives you "No such file or folder" error, just create the folder and file with the command below

```
mkdir ~/.davfs2/
touch  ~/.davfs2/davfs2.conf
```

then proceed with these commands.

```
read -p "box.com email: " boxuser
read -sp "box.com password: " boxpass
echo "https://dav.box.com/dav $boxuser $boxpass" > ~/.davfs2/secrets 
chmod 600 ~/.davfs2/secrets
mount /home/username/box.com
```

Initially it may take some time in order to synchronize all of the files in your box with the newly created folder but after that you should be able to create, delete and overwrite all of your files.

Comment: `sudo echo “https://www.box.com/dav /home/username/box.com davfs rw,user,noauto 0 0″ >> /etc/fstab` command gives me Permission denied error...

Comment: Also cant find the config file -   `echo “use_locks 0″ > ~/.davfs2/davfs2.conf`

Comment: @charlie I've corrected the command

Comment: Just tried this guide and I believe there is one more step to do. The first time I tried to mount the filesystem I got an authentication error, but... I received and SMS from Box saying that I have to use a special verification code in order to use WebDAV. I changed `~/.davfs2/secrets` to read something like `https://dav.box.com/dav my@mail.com "box verification code"` (notice the double quotes) and it worked.

Comment: `davfs2` works allright, but it's pretty slow when navigating between folders (at least when using Dolphin). A proper offline sync would be preferable.

Answer (score 4):

We use Box with Storage Made Easy's Linux App which gives us a mapped drive and sync for Box. It works fine for us and Storage Made Easy is on Box's partner page.

The App is free, works with Ubuntu fine (I'm using with 12.04) and you only need to sign up for a free account to use it. You can download it at:

http://storagemadeeasy.com/index.php?p=&type=&showlogin=&message=

Comment: Sounds nice, but the current version 4.8.3 Ubuntu deb file doesn't install on my Kubuntu 16.04 installation because "Depends: libfuse2 (= 2.9.4-1ubuntu3) but 2.9.4-1ubuntu3.1 is to be installed"

Answer (score 2):

I was facing several issues while following the method in the answer above. And then I found this link :
http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/03/automatically-mount-box-cloud-storage-in-ubuntu-12-04-11-10/
And it has a lot of answers to the blank walls I was facing.

Excerpt of the method in code:

```
sudo apt-get install davfs2
```

run the command below to reconfigure davfs2 so that regular users can mount storages

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure davfs2
```

run the command below to copy davfs2 folder to your home directory

```
sudo cp -r /etc/davfs2/ /home/`<username>`/.davfs2
```

Then run the commands below to change the permissions so that you’re the owner

```
sudo chown -R `<username>` /home/`<username>`/.davfs2/  
gedit ~/.davfs2/secrets
```

When the file opens, add the line shown below at the end and save.

`https://www.box.com/dav <box_username> <box_password>`

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Then add the line shown below at the end and save the file.

```
https://www.box.com/dav/ /home/<username>/box davfs _netdev,rw,user 0 0`
sudo adduser `<username>` davfs2  
mkdir ~/box
```

Remember to replace all  with your box account username, and  with your box account password.

Comment: "the method in the answer above" does not clarify which of the "above" answers you are referring to.   Are you referring to http://askubuntu.com/a/243215/340383 ?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found is webdav-sync: http://www.re.be/webdav_sync/index.xhtml
This is a Java program that offers bidirectional offline syncing with Box (and other WebDAV folders).

The only problem I have encountered is that it may choke on files/directories with non-English characters.

A command like `java -Dbe.re.http.no-expect100 -jar ~/.local/bin/webdav_sync1_1_9.jar -r -u https://username:password@URL -d ~/Box-sync/ -bi -i 30` should do the trick.