# Box Sync using Storage Made Easy, anyone?

Tags: cloud, webdav, online-storage

Box.com does not make a sync client for Linux, which of course is a PITA. Ubuntu forums have several threads on the matter, and the solution suggested by most is to mount the box cloud storage as a webdav mount on nautilus or from cmdline using davfs2. Now although this works okay if you have a fast internet connection, the webdav mount does not have offline capabilities and every change, file save, copy etc. is immediately uploaded to the cloud, which slows down work.

Now someone on [this askubuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237529/how-can-i-use-box-com-to-sync-my-home-directory-across-machines/243198#243198) has suggested using Storage Made Easy's sync client. I tried using the client, and was able sync cloud directories to local directories using the SME Sync client. However, it is also causing sync / trash errors while syncing with box, saying access denied due to insufficient permissions.

Has anyone used Box with Storage Made Easy successfully without sync errors? Would be grateful for any pointers on setting this up correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Linux user that you are using has a read and write permissions to the folders/subfolder/files that you are synchronizing.

Also you can contact SME support on the forum: https://thesmespace.websitetoolbox.com/?forum=166042